# Unity 2021.3 transparent render texture not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to render an object separately from the rest of the scene and pixelate it in the process. I used to cameras, one that renders everything but the object and another that only renders that object (using layers) and the output of the secondary is sent to a render texture that's being displayed in the UI covering the whole screen.

When I enter playmode, it looks alright but as soon as I move the camera around, the last frame of the secondary camera doesn't get deleted so I'm left with a trail of the past frames.

This is how it looks at first:

[image: how its supposed to look]

And this is how it looks when I move the camera:

[image: how it actually looks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix!

Make sure to set the background type of the secondary camera to "solid color", not "uninitialized". See the image below:

[image: this is the correct setting]